# Running Selenium IDE from batch file ignores user-extensions.js and selblocks. Why?

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide, user-extensions.js

Hi I would really like to run a testsuite via the Selenium IDE, which I have started up with some custom commands in user-extensions.js and the SelBLocks extensions (for flow control)
with no success.

Is there a command that will start firefox and run the selenium plugin with the suite and `baseurl` as an argument?

I have had better luck with running the suite with the following command in a batch file (with suitable values for the baseurl, suite & logfile:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "%baseurl%" "%suite%" "%log%" -port 4445
```

But the testrunner will die as soon as it encounters a command defined in `user-extensions.js` and/or a command from `Selblocks`.

Can anyone offer some clues to solving either of the above?

The IDE solution would be better (for me) as we do not have a great deal of java or webdriver talent here.

Answer (score 2):

ANNOUNCEMENT: SelBlocks 2.1 now includes support for Selenium Server. Get the extension file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/refactoror/SelBlocks/master/user-extensions.js

Initial browser support is for firefox, googlechrome, and opera.

Answer (score 0):

Answering part of my own question here...

add the userExtension parameter to the java command to load the user extensions.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -userExtensions "path\to\user-extensions.js" -htmlSuite "*firefox" "%baseurl%" "%suite%" "%log%"
```

Still not sure how to get it to understand the selblocks commands though.

Comment: You would need to seriously re-write the SelBlocks extension.  It uses internal structures of Selenium IDE that just don't exist in the `-htmlsuite` runner.